# How to inject a product field to product display?

Tags: commerce

I have added a field on a product.I want the same field to appear on the product display that is being referenced.I need to do this with code.
How can I do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would personally be using views to either override the product page, or I would hide the fields on the manage display page of the product, and show all the fields using a view in a block with a contextual filter to get the content by ID.

However, you can override the product using a template like node--product.tpl.php and use something like...

```
<?php print render($content['your_field_name']); ?>
```

To print your chosen field.

Comment: Erm I want this field to appear on the node/add page.How can I do this?

Comment: Oh right, I was guessing a bit as your question is quite vague. Can you elaborate, or add more information to your question? If you have added a field to your product type, it should already be on the node/add page

Comment: Hi again,I am using the Commerce Node checkout module.It has an already created by code Product(called Pay to publish).I am adding a new field (a checkbox called Featured) on the Product.After that I want this field to appear on the node/add form,so if user check this,this product will be featured with an increased price.If the Featured field was appearing on the node/add I can create a rule to update the price of the product when added to the cart.Does this make any sense? :)

Comment: Could anyone help me on this please?